# I have an error after having installed Behat + Mink by "pear"

Tags: pear, behat, mink

I have installed Behat and Mink by pear commands and after running Behat using

```
behat -h
```

command, I got an error:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found in
>   /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line
>   975"

What is this suppose to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not install the dependencies required by those packages, so they fail to run. Do *not* force installation with `-f`.

Uninstall the behat and mink packages, then re-install them without `-f`. Also make sure to setup the include path as described in the pear manual.